# {Help }New: Setting Up

Tags: react-native

I am trying to install and do the [Hello World sample](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html) from Facebook.

I have 2 problems:

1. When I run: `create-react-native-app AwesomeProject` I get this error, What does this mean:

> You are currently running Node v4.4.2 but create-react-native-app
>   requires >=6. Please use a supported version of Node.

2. My package.json: `{ "name": "AwesomeProject", "version": "0.1.0", "private": true, "scripts": { "test": "make test", "start": "node index.js" }, "devDependencies": { "react-native-scripts": "1.5.0" } }`

When I npm start I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word at exports.runInThisContext
>   (vm.js:53:16) at Module._compile (module.js:373:25) at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10) at Module.load
>   (module.js:343:32) at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12) at
>   Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10) at startup (node.js:139:18)
>   at node.js:968:3

This is the code I copy and paste from Facebook Hello World sample.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you have'not clone `AwesomeProject` successful yet. You got the above error because you had older version of NodeJS (v4.4.2). Please follow step by step on below guidance:

- Firstly, you need to install new one with version larger than 6.x.x (check and download it on the offical site).
- Then, run `create-react-native-app AwesomeProject` again and make sure it is done with succesful message
- Finally, run `react-native start` to launch the app.

Cheer!

Comment: Thanks. This work.  FYI Going through brew doesn't work on update.

Comment: @NhanCao I thought it just install and remove package on the OS and you have to check it by yourself because you will face the problem that is related to node version many times in the future.